# Creating a local variable to represent a range of numbers within a xpath tr[ ]?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I"m trying to scrape Oregon teacher licensure information that looks like [this](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=535454R3L38) or [this](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=595R8ZPBL97)(this is publicly available data). My problem is that since there are hundreds of teachers with differing amounts of licenses and district restrictions, the html tag numbers that I'm using to grab the data change with each new combination that I haven't explicitly coded for.

This is part of my code to scrape the data in for first link.

```
for t in range(0,1000): #Drawing from a txt file with web address ids

    address = 'http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=' + lines[t]

    page = requests.get(address)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    if "District Restriction" in dist_rest_find5: 
            print "dist rest 5"

            #Put Teacher License info into lists
        if "License Type" in tree.xpath('//tr[18]//text()'):
            test1 = tree.xpath('//tr[19]//text()')
            test1 = ([s.strip('\r') for s in test1])
            test1 = ([s.strip(' ') for s in test1])
            test1 = filter(None, test1)
            ltest1.append(test1)
        else:
            ltest1.append('')

        if "License Type" in tree.xpath('//tr[26]//text()'):
            test2 = tree.xpath('//tr[27]//text()')
            test2 = ([s.strip('\r') for s in test2])
            test2 = ([s.strip(' ') for s in test2])
            test2 = filter(None, test2)
            ltest2.append(test2)
        else:
            ltest2.append('')
```

I've realized that coding each new combination will take weeks and I've thought of a solution but I don't know how to translate it into Python.

I would want where the number in `if "License Type" in tree.xpath('//tr[18]//text()')` is to be a range that cycles through all of the `tr[]` tags until it meets the condition, appends the License Type to a list, then moves to the next `if "License Type" in tree.xpath('//tr[26]//text()')` statement. I wouldn't want there to be duplicates so what is taken from the second statement can't overlap the first. In Stata I would create a `local` in place of the number but I don't know if the same idea would be used in Python.

Example of the output I want.

[image]

Let me know if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you basically want to grab all of the licenses from every teacher's page. The idea here would be to locate the row that has the `License Type` text inside the first cell and then get the first [following `tr` sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) of that row.

Implementation:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


url = "http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=535454R3L38"
page = requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
for license_row in tree.xpath(".//tr[td[1] = 'License Type']/following-sibling::tr[1]"):
    license_data = license_row.xpath(".//td/text()")
    print(license_data)
```

Prints:

```
['Initial II Teaching', '5/31/2015', '6/9/2018', 'Active']
['Initial II School Counselor', '6/10/2014', '6/9/2017', 'Active']
['Initial Administrator', '6/10/2014', '7/10/2016', 'Active']
['Initial I School Counselor', '6/10/2008', '6/9/2011', 'Expired']
['Conditional Permit', '10/3/2006', '10/2/2008', 'Expired']
['Initial School Counselor', '4/26/2005', '6/9/2008', 'Expired']
['Initial I Teaching', '6/13/2002', '6/9/2006', 'Expired']
['Conditional Permit', '12/21/2002', '12/20/2005', 'Expired']
['Conditional Permit', '3/1/2004', '12/20/2005', 'Expired']
['Conditional Permit', '9/1/2004', '4/25/2005', 'Expired']
['Transitional Teaching', '7/24/2001', '7/24/2004', 'Expired']
['Expedited Service', '7/24/2001', '7/24/2004', 'Expired']
['Restricted Transitional Teaching', '7/24/2001', '7/24/2004', 'Expired']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was curious if you know how you would assign each bracketed portion that you printed into separate columns in a csv?

Comment: @otteheng okay, please consider creating a separate question if you experience difficulties. Thanks.